# PHP Include_path not working apache server

Tags: php

Currently in my PHP coding I have to put `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']"./` in front of every file path in my web code. I previously asked and discovered I could set include_path. I tried setting this in both .htaccess and the .conf for the virtual host, but it just fails out and doesn't work/load the include.

Code: 
this is in the vhost .conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value include_path ":/var/www/testdomains/domain-test1.local/php"
    php_admin_flag engine on
</IfModule>
```

(I've tried putting this outside the IfModule area with no success.

My .php file on the webserver:

```
<?php require  "/authcheck.php"  ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need an include_path to require other php-files in the same directory. If you have e.g. an index.php and a authcheck.php in the same directory just remove the leading slash like `<?php require "authcheck.php" ?>`. You need an include path to make files available that are not in the document-root of the webserver.

Comment: If you want to include a file relatively from the file that does the including, use `require __DIR__ . '/path/to/the/file.php';` - The `__DIR__ `-constant contains the absolute path to the file it's written in, which will make it work even if you include this file from another file, in another location.

Comment: I'm trying to clean up code and the include_path seemed like the best way to do that. Either way, I'd rather be able to just include the headers and additional info without having to worry about relative paths and just write everything based on the Document Root. Is the code I've included above just not possible?